# Django choices in Admin when Enum is used

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

I have a model where I am using Enum for choices:

```
class Agreement(models.Model):
    class Category(enum.Enum):
        EULA = 0
        PROVIDER = 1

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.IntegerField(
        choices=[(choice.name, choice.value)
                 for choice in Category])
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    content = models.TextField()
```

I register it using simple admin site registration:

```
admin.site.register(Agreement)
```

When admin site renders the object it doesn't allow me to save it?  Has anyone had a similar issue?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#choices):

> The first element in each tuple is the actual value to be set on the model, and the second element is the human-readable name.

`name` and `value` should be the other way around, like this:

```
category = models.IntegerField(
    choices=[(choice.value, choice.name)
             for choice in Category])
```

because `category` is an integer field and `name` returns a string.